# Unable to set Ellipsis for Labels

Tags: android, appcelerator, label, ellipsis, appcelerator-titanium

As suggested in the appcelerator community, tried using ellipsize---->true
horizontalWrap--->false but it did not work

Please advise. Thanks

Comment: Please have a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and include some sample code, list of things you've tried, expected vs actual result etc. That gets you more help.

Answer (score 2):

Set default `width`

Ex:-

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    backgroundColor : "#FFF"
});

var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    font : {
        fontSize : '32dp'
    },
    width : '250dp',
    height : '75dp',
    ellipsize : true,
    wordWrap : false,
    html : "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
});

win.add(label);
win.open();
```